# Custom view for NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I've looked through the related questions and have examined [Apple's sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MenuItemView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004136) but these examples do almost everything programmatically. I would prefer to do as much as possible in IB.

My question is: what is the general procedure to accomplish this?

1. Create a new xib file to hold an `NSView` subclass with the various
   embedded UI elements.
2. Create the `NSView` subclass in code.
3. As I add items to my menu (which occurs dynamically) I'd create the
   `NSMenuItem` and then call the instance's `setView:` method.

I'm confused about setting FilesOwner in IB (is my custom NSView subclass FilesOwner in this case)?

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: you may clarify what the view will do or/and its complexity. Thus allowing better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new xib, if the custom view is more complex. If it is a very simple view, you can create it in code.

Regarding File's owner and structure, I would use a `NSViewController`if the custom menu item view has its own xib file. Then instantiate this view controller in code and assign its view to the `NSMenuItem`. That way you can handle organizational stuff through the controller and keep along the MVC paradigm.